# Android CheckBox in List to Right

Tags: android, checkbox, move

I am creating a list which consists of an image, text, and a check box for each line. I use Table Layout but I want to move checkbox place to right, `gravity:right` did not work. What can I do for this?
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="" 

            />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: try setting the weight of CheckBox.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Please write an answer for this, and as soon as you do kindly comment on my answer and I will delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the weight of CheckBox

So your code now would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
             />

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer given by [Jagdeep Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256431/jagdeep-singh). 
Note: I removed the answer from the question so I had to put it here. But I will remove this as soon as Jagdeep writes an answer and I am notified

Comment: You moved this from the question... You should have commented, so the person who actually came up with this solution can get credit for it. If they don't respond, you can always come back and post it as an answer, like you did. This is just plagiarising.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling I am sorry, I will just do that

Comment: @DakshShah Your answer is perfect, I had just given the idea to user3553928 so that he/she can search and apply to the problem.